# What is the type of every item in CheckedListBox.Items?

Tags: .net, winforms, checkedlistbox

I need to know what is the type of every element in `CheckedListBox.Items`? Is it `ListViewItem`, `Object` or what?

I also want to know how can I bind a `DataTable` to a `CheckedListBox` and set every items ID and text in windows forms?

Comment: OK, SO CheckedListbox DOES have properties like DataSource, DisplayMember and ValueMember but they does not appear in intellisense.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type depends on the objects that you use to fill the checked list box. You can use a `DataTable` by using the following code:

```
var table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("ID");
table.Columns.Add("NAME");

table.Rows.Add("1", "John Doe");
table.Rows.Add("2", "Jane Doe");

this.checkedListBox1.DataSource = table;
this.checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
this.checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "NAME";
```

In this case since you will be filling the checked list box using a `DataTable` doing `this.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems` after checking one or more items will output an `ObjectCollection` where each item in the collection is a `DataRowView` instance.

To obtain the checked items you could do:

```
var checkedIds = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in this.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    var dataRowView = (DataRowView)item;

    checkedIds.Add((string)dataRowView["ID"]);
}
```

Comment: CheckedListbox does NOT have those properties (DataSource , ValueMember and displayMember)

Comment: Have you tried to run the code at least? They do not appear in Intellisense, but the control has those properties.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me; the state never changed.  This is the code that I came up with that does work.

```
Private Sub SetCLBXState(ByVal DesiredState As Boolean)
    For ItemIndex As Integer = 0 To CLBXExclude.Items.Count - 1
        CLBXExclude.SetItemChecked(ItemIndex, DesiredState)
    Next
End Sub
```